# Xcode 14.1 Black square on live preview

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode14, live-preview

I've installed the new version of Xcode (14.1, build 14B47b) and I'm having issues with the canvas live preview. When "Live" is selected I only see a black square, but if I select "Selectable", I can see a preview of my view.
Is anyone else experiencing something like this? Did I miss something in my setup?

Thanks for your help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Restarting solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just started seeing the same issue on 14.1. Tried restarting Xcode and turning the canvas off/on, but neither worked. However, I switch target device (to a different simulator) and it rendered correctly.